# Access "Application" object in ASP.Net MVC to store application wide variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I store a variable or object application wide in ASP.net MVC?

In regular ASP, you had the Application object and in ASP.net too apparently.

I'm using ASP.net MVC 2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a controller you should be able to do this:

```
this.HttpContext.Application["foo"] = "bar";
```

Comment: For testability I'd be inclined to interface out this call to remove the dependency on HttpContext within the controller.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC relies on ASP.NET. so you can use almost any ASP.NET Feature.

Comment: Beware for race conditions, you should hold a lock while reading or writing such global state. Multiple requests can be handled concurrently by different threads.