# Using Multiple Config files for a shared MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration

I have an MVC application that consists of a directory with all the necessary files to run except the css and master view.  In IIS, I have several sites set up that all use the same directory, but then have virtual directories set up for each site's unique css and template.  This works very well, although I am now wanting to have a separate config for each unique site (for basic settings like site id to query my db, etc).  I created new virtual directories for each site and added a config.xml in each, added the following to my global.asax.cs file in the application start method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //read in all the application variables from the config file on startup
        XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
        Doc.Load(Server.MapPath("/Config/Config.xml"));

        XmlNodeList VarLst = Doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//AppVars/*");
        foreach (XmlNode VarNod in VarLst)
        {
            RecursiveDescent(VarNod, "");
        }
        string[] AppVars = new string[Application.Count];
        AppVars = Application.AllKeys;

        //How do I now use Application.AllKeys from a controller?
    }
```

Now, I have my keys, but can't seem to figure out how to use them in a controller.  Normally, if I was using the app settings in the web config and wanted to set my siteId, I'd just use:

```
int siteId = Convert.ToInt16(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteId"]);
```

but now I want to use

```
Application["SiteId"];
```

but it's not like a webforms code behind that inherits from the page class and I'm not getting the concept on how to get the Applications settings in an MVC controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this other question: [Access "Application" object in ASP.Net MVC to store application wide variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430839/access-application-object-in-asp-net-mvc-to-store-application-wide-variables)

```
this.HttpContext.Application["SiteId"]
```